# My code will not write "No files to process"

Tags: powershell

My code will not display "No files to process" on the screen. It is supposed to count the files in a directory and if there are none then it should display "No files to process"  and then exit.

```
# Function Measure, counts files to see if there are any to process.
Function Measure
{
$Measure = ( Get-ChildItem C:\temp\BDMDump\ | Measure-Object ).Count
    If ($Measure = "0") 
            {Write-Host "No files to process"|Exit} 
    else
            {Write-Host "There are files to process.."}
}
```

I expect to see "No files to process".

Comment: A simple `if((Get-ChildItem C:\temp\BDMDump\ -File).Count){"There are files to process.."} else {"No files to process"}` would do.

Answer (score 5):

There are 4 issues here:

1. You are using the '=' which is only used for assignment. Use '-eq for comparison.
2. You are enclosing your integer with quotes, converting it into a string. Just remove the quotes.
3. As mentioned by ineedalife, you're piping to Exit. You should instead use a semi-colon and the return keyword `; return` to exit the function. Even this is probably not needed if the function doesn't do anything else.
4. You are trying to use "Measure" as the function's name. This is an alias to Measure-Object! Simply change the name to something else, like "Measure-Files"

Additionally, you could remove `| Measure-Object` because the object System.IO.FileInfo which is returned by Get-ChildItem already has a "Count" method.

Here's a revised copy of your code with all the changes:

```
Function Measure-Files {
  $Measure = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\BDMDump\"
  If ($Measure.Count -eq 0) 
  { Write-Host "No files to process"; return } 
  else
  { Write-Host "There are files to process.." }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add that "=" is an assignment, while -eq is one of powershell's operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

Comment: I just tried this and it still does not work...If ($Measure -eq 0)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems
1. `Exit` can not be Piped to. If you want to exit the session use`Exit-PSSession` this will close the window.
2. "Is equal to" should be changed from `=` to `-eq`
3. `"0"` should be changed to `0` as it is an integer

```
If ($Measure -eq 0) 
   {Write-Host "No files to process"|Exit-PSSession} 
    else
        {Write-Host "There are files to process.."}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and it does not work for me....($Measure -eq "0")

Comment: Is Exit declared as a Function in your script. I don't think it is a default function. If you remove the Exit in `{Write-Host "No files to process"|Exit} ` It works